# iPhone design resolution in Photoshop

Tags: iphone, cordova, photoshop

I am wondering about how to change the design in photoshop for the new iPhone 5.

Usually I create design/background for iPhone in Photoshop, with resolution **640x960** for retina. Since the retina resolution is propotional to the older ones I can just reduce to 320x480.

But what about the iPhone 5. The Screen is higher. I'ts a new resolution ( **1136 x 640** )

What is the best solution for photoshop design to display on iphone4s< and iPohne 5?

**How can I handle that without creating a new design?**
And how can I tell the app just to use it if it's the iPhone 5?
(I am using **PhoneGap/Cordova**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an original design using 960x640. Then you can just add a different layer positioning your elements for the 1136x640 resolution. When exporting, hide the tall layer if you want to target iPhones < 5. When targeting the iPhone 5, just have your layer as a top view, and you can change the artboard on the fly.

Also, iOS 6 won't automatically target iPhone 5 images (except Default). So if you want to use different images you would have to check yourself for the height.

Basically, if your screenSize.height == 568, you're using an iPhone 5.